# Row count from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have inherited a SQL query which runs for eternity and I am trying to improve the query performance by eliminating predicates that are redundant.

For example, the base table is like this

```
| itemNo | itemType    |
|--------|-------------|
| 1000   | camera      |
| 1000   | camera      |
| 1000   | camera      |
| 1001   | mobilePhone |
| 1002   | VR gear     |
| 1003   | other       |
```

and the SQL query contains a predicate like this (in reality it contains many redundant predicates). In this case, this particular predicate is useless because the `itemNo` can never be more than 4 digits as it is a restriction applied on the data level.

```
select distinct itemNo, itemType
from @src 
where datalength(itemNo)=4
```

I need to carefully eliminate the predicates one after another and want to compare the total rowcount with the base query and after the removal of the predicate to determine if it is safe for me to remove the predicate **`as long as the row count is the same before and after removal`**.

Is there any way, to get the total row count of a particular query without SQL requiring to execute the base query first? Because the query takes >45 minutes now and I want to avoid waiting for that long to see the total row count of the base query.

I know, I can do this

`select @@ROWCOUNT` but it also executes the query first before giving the result.

This is what I tried

```
declare @src as table (itemNo integer, itemType varchar(max));
insert into @src
select * from
(values(1000,'camera'),(1000,'camera'), (1000,'camera'), (1001,'mobilePhone'),(1002,'VR gear'),(1003,'other')) t(a,b)

--base query
select distinct itemNo, itemType
from @src 
where datalength(itemNo)=4

select @@ROWCOUNT

/* this does not work
select COUNT(distinct itemNo, itemType)
from @src 
where datalength(itemNo)=4
*/
```

`SELECT @@VERSION=Microsoft SQL Server 2016`

Comment: There are estimated count of rows, but they are typically off. I would run the real query just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The *best* thing to do would be to use a proper diff tool to see the difference in results. Try DataGrip. Yes you need to run the query again

Comment: You could add a windowed count to the query. But I think this an unsafe strategy for performance analysis. An expression may seem useless at the time you execute it, but become meaningful next week/month/etc

Comment: Row counts alone do not guarantee that your changed query returns the **same resultset** as the prior version. Be careful what you assume. TBH tuning a query should start with an examination of the execution plan.

Comment: I assume your predictates are all used in a where clause, connected by AND..  correct?  Can you give me a few examples, in addition to the one you shared datalength(itemNo)=4 ?

Comment: You need to snapshot the results into a table `select... into... from` and after refactoring repeat and then compare the two snapshot's unique keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar situation, but I'm not sure if it'll help you.

In my situation, I had several different WHERE clause conditions, like:

`datalength(itemNo)=4`

`Column2 IS NOT NULL`

`Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 < 100`

`Column1 > 12`

What I wanted to do, was run each and every element individually, and count the results of each.

So what I did, was I used this free [SQL Generator](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22conditional_agg%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22src%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Column_1%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Column_2%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22itemNo%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22rules%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22value_list%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%22datalength%28itemNo%29%3D4%22%2C%22Column2%20IS%20NOT%20NULL%22%2C%22Column1%20IS%20NOT%20NULL%20AND%20Column1%20%3C%20100%22%2C%22Column1%20%3E%2012%22%5D%7D%2C%22agg_column%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column%22%7D%2C%22agg%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22agg%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22COUNT%22%7D%2C%22distinct%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22boolean%22%2C%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22conditional_agg%22%7D) to generate the SQL for me:

```
SELECT 'datalength(itemNo)=4' AS rule_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) as QTY 
FROM src 
WHERE datalength(itemNo)=4

UNION ALL
SELECT 'datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12' AS rule_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) as QTY 
FROM src 
WHERE datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12

UNION ALL
SELECT 'datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12 AND Column2 IS NOT NULL' AS rule_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) as QTY 
FROM src 
WHERE datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12 AND Column2 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL
SELECT 'datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12 AND Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 < 100' AS rule_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) as QTY 
FROM src 
WHERE datalength(itemNo)=4 AND Column1 > 12 AND Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 IS NOT NULL AND Column1 < 100
```

This SQL would be time consuming to write, but the Rasgo tool will generate the SQL for you. You just have to setup your table structure on the right-hand side and then add your WHERE conditions.

The other thing that is possible, is have it generate all combinations of the rules as well, so it will combine all 4 into every possible combination of 3, 2, and 1 condition. That obviously explodes your SQL depending on how many predicates you have.